# Why is there no IQueue<T> or IStack<T> interface in the .NET Framework?

Tags: .net

I wanted to write an object that operated on a queue-like interface. I went searching for `IQueue<T>`, but came back surprisingly empty-handed.

There are the following collection-related interfaces:

- `ICollection<T>`
- `IList<T>`
- `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>`
- `ISet<T>`

What made these types of collections get well-defined interfaces? Why do stacks and queues not warrant an interface?

Comment: A stack or queue is a fairly trivial implementation of a sorted list, so why would they build in something that's like 2 lines of code so that it could instead be 1?

Comment: @Russell Steen what is *sorted* in queue? Linked list may be?

Comment: @Russell Steen Implementation-details shouldn't be a factor in having a well-defined *interface*.

Comment: @Andrey - Good catch, sort is irrelevant really.  Thanks!

Comment: @Programming Hero - So you're saying interfaces should be written with no consideration of what use they might serve (ie, potential implementations)?  If that's the logic what justification could there possibly be for leaving *anything* out.   Why not just include every potential interface known to science?  -  The real world dictates that some choices about likely implementations have to be considered to determine where the .NET teams time is best spent.

Comment: The hallmark of great API design is not what you put in but what you dare to leave out.

Comment: @Hans: The hallmark of great API design is usability, not just what's put in or left out!

Comment: I would like IQeue<T> so I could substitute for the standard implementation while refactoring queue-using code (example 1: thread-safety, example 2: pre-allocated max capacity and no dynamic allocations). I'm sure the real reason is just a matter of design and implementation priorities. Feels like an oversight to me, oh well.

Comment: I think the main reason is it was a long time ago. They had a smaller team and budget back then I imagine. Also their design philosophy has evolved over time. I think if they had to do it again they would add it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, because there would be one to one mapping from those interfaces to classes that implement them (except latest `ConcurrentQueue`). But other mentioned interfaces have lots of classes that implement them.

Expanding a bit. We can't know real motivation of BCL team. But i have a feeling that when they created `Queue` and `Stack` those classes looked so trivial so they decided not to abstract them out to interfaces. Reason is obvious: classes looked so simple but complete at the same time so there was no reason to create different implementations of them in BCL. Then came `ConcurrentQueue` and previous statement became slightly incorrect.

As it pointed `Queue` and `ConcurrentQueue` don't have that much similar to make them implement single interface.

Comment: +1 Countering downvote. i would like to see the answer expanded a bit but i don't think it deserves a -1.

Comment: @Paul Sasik thanks, i expanded,

Comment: `ConcurrentQueue<T>` also has (mostly) different semantics than `Queue<T>`; their only real shared abstraction is `Enqueue`.

Comment: I would love an interface that both stack and queue implement, to easily create lifo fifo behaviour. void Add(T), T Take(), int Count { get; }. I can then implement it in min max heaps for more flexibility

Comment: @BasSmit nothing stops you from doing that. The only thing that common interface gives you is that you can pass different implementations.

Comment: @Andrey I am doing that :) And you are correct, passing implementations with different behaviour is the intended purpose. There are benefits to the framework providing this interface though, it could be used in framework api's, I cant modify those. It could also be used in third party api's, which would then allow me to reuse my own code that implements that interface.

Comment: This answer actually contradicts itself. First it says there would be a one to one mapping. "Then came ConcurrentQueue and previous statement became slightly incorrect." Thats exactly the point, you cant predict the future and all possible use cases, which is why providing an interface is a good idea in a framework context, as it at least has a chance of catering to unforeseen developments and usecases.

Comment: @BasSmit it is generally useless to argue why the developers of the standard library didn't do something, it is just fact. Anyway, I think that Queue and ConcurrentQueue should not be used interchangeably because there are too many differences between them.

Answer (score 5):

I think the very existence of new classes in .NET 4 `ConcurrentQueue<T>` and `ConcurrentStack<T>` proves your point that there should have been `IQueue<T>` and `IStack<T>` interfaces.  Even if they didn't exist originally, they should have been added in .NET 4.

I have had to create my own custom Stack implementations in the past in .NET and agree that having a standard interface would have been beneficial.

Answer (score 4):

I would guess that you don't see Stack or Queue interfaces is because of the natures of the collections. The collection interfaces that you listed which do have interfaces are random access while Stacks and Queues are not. They have to be accessed in a very particular manner (FIFO or LIFO) and therefore cannot be used generally. So it makes sense to just use those collections as generic implementations but not through interfaces. In other words, because of the constraints that LIFO/FIFO put on a collection, there is very little (or nothing) that can be done differently by a class that implemented a theoretical IStack or IQueue.

To exercise this idea you could create your own IStack and/or IQueue and then implement them in a class. You will see that the functionality you expose will be completely pass-through. E.g. You will end up simply forwarding or returning requests and results to an internal Stack or Queue collection. And there will be little or nothing of potential value-added in that pass-through functionality.

Comment: What about something like `ConcurrentQueue<T>` (which actually does now exist in the BCL)? Don't you think it would have made sense for `Queue<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to both implement a common interface?

Comment: @LukeH: That's a more specialized collection though it still follows the FIFO semantics so i would expect that there a iConcurrentQueue interface wold not really be useful.

Comment: I will actually be creating an `IQueue<T>` interface! My implementation will use a synchronized store which persists to disc. It would've been preferable to re-use an existing interface, rather than define my own thing though!

Comment: Maybe not, but a common abstraction across `Queue<T>` and `ConcurrentQueue<T>` would still be useful, even if they just made `CQ<T>` a genuine specialisation of `Q<T>`.

Comment: Good points all. I was simply waxing on the reasons why MS might not have bothered writing IQueue/IStack.

Answer (score 4):

Why *should* the .NET framework have `IQueue<T>` and `IStack<T>` interfaces? What would they buy?

> What made these types of collections
>   get well-defined interfaces?

The Base Class Libraries actually use all of the those interfaces (`IList` etc): in each case, there are a bunch of other classes for which it made more sense to interact with the interface abstraction than a concrete type.

> Why do stacks and queues not warrant
>   an interface?

Probably because there weren't any BCL classes that needed `IStack<T>` and `IQueue<T>` and there were no obvious or likely use-cases for those abstractions.

I realize this isn't a satisfying philosophical answer, but it looks like the framework designers were really pragmatic about what got interfaces: they made them when they needed them.

Comment: The pragmatic aspect is a good one to consider. I certainly wouldn't create an interface I didn't have an immediate use for.

Comment: IMO this is probably the "true" answer. I expect the designers didn't create many of the included interfaces until they had a need for them.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's because Stack and Queue are very special concepts and to my knowledge there are no other classes implementing a special form of a stack or queue.

**EDIT:**

Ok, there is now a `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, which seems to negate my conclusion. Maybe, back in the days when C# 1.0 was still in beta, the language designers thought there will never be a special form of a queue/stack and now it's too late to introduce an interface for it.

That's a lot of guessing. I hope, Eric Lippert will see this question and post an "official" statement. :-)

Comment: question was about generalization, not specialization

Comment: @Andrey: What I wanted to say is that the concept of a queue is perfectly covered by the Queue class, so there might be no need for an interface and another implementation of a queue. Same with stack.

Comment: @VVS: Regarding your edit... When MS introduced `SortedSet<T>` in .NET4 it didn't stop them introducing the `ISet<T>` interface and retro-fitting it to `HashSet<T>`.

Comment: In principle a DEQ would derive from an IStack and an IQueue

Comment: @annakta: I never used a deque in my code so I have no experience with it. Would it make sense to use a deque, as if it was a queue or a stack? Because that's what you're saying if you implement an interface.

Comment: @LukeH: Agreed. That assumption was obviously wrong. All I'm doing here is educated guessing.

Comment: @annakata: If you `Pop` an item from a deque, do you take it from the head or from the tail? To me it seems like there is little reason for a deque to act like a regular queue and even less like a stack.

Comment: @VVS - In a word, yes. Only it's a queue AND not a queue OR.

Comment: @VVS: As for Popping it doesn't really matter if it's from the head or tail so long as it's the opposite end from Shifting/Dequeuing, in this respect the terms are nominal.

Comment: I have no "official" position on any aspect of the design of the BCL. You might consider asking at the BCLTeam blog if you want an answer straight from the team.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there was any particular reason.  If I had my druthers, there would be a lot more discretely-defined interfaces, even if there weren't classes which implemented them alone. For example, I might have implemented a QueueStack(Of T), which would implement IGetNext(Of T), IGetNextWait(Of T), and IClear(Of T), along with IQueue(Of T), IWaitQueue(Of T), IStack(Of T), and IWaitStack(Of T).  People consuming an object could specify narrowly what it was they actually needed, and implementers would only have to implement what they'd claim to support.